# Mesh with shape key animation - ok in Blender, wrong in Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity, shape-keys

I have a mesh with shape key animation. I use actions in order to get separate animations after exporting this model to Unity.

Everything looks fine in Blender.
But **after export to Unity, when I call an animation, the model becomes very small and turns at the wrong angle**.

Maybe I shouldn't apply location, rotation, and scale after I finished creating and animation shape keys... But still - **everything looks right in Blender**, so is there **a way to fix this problem with exporting to Unity?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I had this problem too in Unity. I couldn't figure out how to work around it. I had to apply the rotations,scales, and positions BEFORE creating animation/shapekeys.

Comment: @TTTTTTa I see, good luck to you in your animations!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the scaling issue, be sure you select your mesh in Object mode and check the scale transform. If it's not set to 1.0, apply your scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and selecting *Scale* from the drop down menu that appears. If you're using an armature, make sure your mesh and armature have their scales applied before binding them together.

To fix the rotation issue, check that any rotation changes have also been applied, similarly to how you apply scaling changes. If you're exporting with FBX, change your Up and Forward directions in the FBX export screen to the correct directions for your mesh.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. I added keystroke formatting to your post. To learn how to do that yourself in the future, you can click the [edit] link and check what I changed. You may also want to take the [tour].